# is "openssl rsa" subcommand deprecated in favor of "openssl pkey"?

Tags: openssl

To show information of a RSA private key file, both

```
openssl rsa --text < key
```

and

```
openssl pkey --text < key
```

works,
obviously the latter is easier to understand and remember because "pkey" subcommand seems be a unified interface for all kinds of private keys.

However, from the openssl man page, I could not find any description about which is recommended.

Can anyone tell me which is recommended? or none is deprecated?

EDIT: also, there is a "openssl pkcs8" subcommand.

Really don't understand how does openssl design its subcommands, many are not user-oriented, but algorithm oriented.

Answer (score 1):

oh, I figure it out.

```
openssl genrsa > root.key
openssl rsa < root.key
```

are a pair. The result file will be like "...BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY...",

they are almost equivalent to

```
openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA > root.key
openssl pkey < root.key
```

except that the latter produce "...BEGIN PRIVATE KEY...", note the "RSA" word is not output.